# How add primitives or other objects to scene using python

Tags: python, scripting

I found many old information. Where is simple example to add all primitives (completly working example with actual blender)

I need put cylinder, and move it into specyfic location, seting scale and assign color and name. Im not using mesh, faces etc, I need only primitives like box or torus....

Comment: This site is more for single questions at a time, importing would be a different topic to creating primitives. See if [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/75896/935) helps with importing.

Answer (score 6):

There are several operators that [add primitive objects](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/search.html?q=ops%20primitive) to a scene, look at the reference for each to see all available options.

An example of adding several objects -

```
import bpy

for x in range(10):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cone_add(location=(x,0.0,1.0), radius1=0.5, radius2=0.1)
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location=(x,0.0,2.0), radius=0.5)
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_ico_sphere_add(location=(x,0.0,3.0), size=0.5)
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_monkey_add(location=(x,0.0,4.0), radius=0.5)
```

You can also find [similar operators](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.ops.html#bmesh.ops.create_grid) available when using [bmesh](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.html), which is a better option when you want to edit mesh objects, or build more complex models.

Note that after you add an object using one of the primitive operators, it becomes the active object, that means you can get the object using `bpy.context.active_object` and make further adjustments after you have created it.

[This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/77885/935) gives an example of creating multiple materials and assigning them to different faces.

Comment: How put color to this primitoves? This is trouble because colors is less than objects. I need 4 colorb but objects have 100. Trouble is how create materials without objects.

Comment: I have color in html #hexhexhex or in rgb in integer

Comment: @MarkoLustro [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/63349/935) is an example of creating a BI material. [Cycles nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23446/935) takes a bit more. Blender takes rgb values as floats, that is 0.0-1.0 matches 0-255 so if you have red as 127 use `127/255` to get the float equivalent. You use `int('BB', 16)` to turn the hex into an int or together as `int('BB',16)/255`.

Comment: Yes , colors working, thanks. The trouble is how add this color to the scene and save it in 'F' mode (alvays in blender file)

Comment: [`mat.use_fake_user = True`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.ID.html#bpy.types.ID.use_fake_user) - that property is common between all items that support a fake user.